# VBA Selenium isn't returning the first column of data into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, scrape

I've installed Selenium, got everything working except the first column of data is not being returned and posted in Excel from the site.  I'm sure it's something simple.  Anyone, please help.

```
Sub PullData()

Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim rowc, cc, columnC As Integer
rowc = 2
driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/australian-dollar_quotes_settlements_options.html#optionProductId=8093&optionExpiration=8094-Q0&tradeDate=08%2F10%2F2020"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

'Header
For Each th In driver.FindElementByClass("cmeTable").FindElementByTag("thead").FindElementsByTag("tr")
cc = 1
For Each t In th.FindElementsByTag("th")
Sheet1.Cells(1, cc).Value = t.Text
cc = cc + 1
Next t
Next th

'Body
For Each tr In driver.FindElementByClass("cmeTable").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
columnC = 2
For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
Sheet1.Cells(rowc, columnC).Value = td.Text
columnC = columnC + 1
Next td
rowc = rowc + 1
Next tr
End Sub
```

Comment: You start the headers in Column1 but then start the data in Column2.  Is that intentional ?

Comment: Yeah, because I need room for the first column, that is missing.  I originally had it in Column 1 but it's still the same results.

Comment: The first cell in each row is a `th`, not a `td`, so you will need to get that first, before looping over the remaining `td` elements.

Comment: That's what the section under Header is doing, it loops the `th` first.  First column doesn't pull for either the Header `th` or Body `td`.

Comment: No, the section looping over the header only finds `th` elements in the `thead` - it will not locate any `th` which are contained in `tr` under the `tbody`

Comment: I've tweaked many times in different ways, including trying to locate any `th` which contain `tr` under the `tbody`.

Comment: `th` do not contain `tr` - it's the other way round.  I don't have selenium installed so I'm unable to tweak your code...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Selenium but here's the basic outline using IE automation:

```vb
    Dim Explorer As Object, doc, tbls, tr, td
    Set Explorer = GetIEByUrl("https://www.cmegroup.com/trading*") 'function to get an open window by URL
    
    Set doc = Explorer.document
    
    Set tbls = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    'look at the first table: get the rows in the table body
    For Each tr In tbls(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody") (0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        'the first cell is a th
        Debug.Print tr.getElementsByTagName("th")(0).innerText
        'the rest of the cells are td's
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            Debug.Print td.innerText
        Next td
        Debug.Print "***********************"
    Next tr
```

Comment: I just discovered the data that is not pulling is described as `class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn"`.  Any way to code to adjust for this?

Comment: "invisibleElement" is just a className - it has no special significance in HTML.  The above works fine for me (with IE)

Comment: It worked for me in IE as well.  However, IE is unstable, super slow, and keeps crashing when I perform on multiple pages.  Hence moving over to Chrome.

Comment: I'm looking at the URL you have above, and I'm not seeing that class name.

Comment: I can't anymore either ... hmmm.  Strange, I didn't see it at first either.  At some point it showed as as that's what I copied/pasted from for the above comment.  Either way, code pulls everything except the first column "Strike" for both header and body.

Comment: I just tested with Selenium and see the same thing as you - looks like a problem with Selenium or it's just different in some way from how IE handles that table...?